# Add signature into PDF in perl

Tags: perl, pdf

How can I sign a pdf file using digital signature in perl? I'm able to extract the content of pdf and to generate signature string via

```
# $content -> pdf content to be signed

my $private_key Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($key_string);
$private_key->use_md5_hash();
my $signature = $private_key->sign($content);
```

Consequently, the $signature can be converted into hex format, but I don't know how to add it into PDF file. I know that the signature in hex form should be placed in /Contents field and the range of signed text is given by /ByteRange array.

Is there any module for this purpose? Or can you give me any advice how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you may find this script interesting ... http://mschuette.name/files/pdfsign.pl it uses PDF::API2 and Crypt::OpenSSL todo its magic ... it could probably serve as a basis for creating something of your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use File::Slurp;

my $keystring = read_file('private_key.pem');
my $private_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($keystring);
$private_key->use_md5_hash();
my $signature = $private_key->sign($plaintext);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the principle of signature creation. But PDF format is unique in that it includes support for signatures to be embedded in the document itself. So, the question is not "how to create signature?", but "how to embed the signature into PDF?".

If there is not a Perl module which enables it (something like iText for Java), I would appreciate some links to description and explanation of this process.


In Java, this can be done via iText library. But I need to do it in perl. So if there is no

Answer (score 0):

I can sign PDF with the data obtained

```
my $webid = Web::ID->new(certificate => $ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT});

$ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}
$ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0}
$ENV{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_1}
```